# how to notify a user when a new sql record inserted?

Tags: php, sql, notifications

I m working in a simple private messaging script using PHP and SQL , and I need I way to notify the user when a new message is received, maybe in a simple notification bar , something like this  :

New Messages [ **6** ]

Here is the database

```
TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) NOT NULL )
```

as you see , it's very simple.

any Ideas ?
Sorry for my terrible English, Have a good day.

Comment: `if(condition) { mail() }` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Send an email as suggested above or if you want it to alert a user on your page try an Ajax call on a interval.

Comment: @Izion , What is the " Ajax call on a interval " ? I m still a beginners .

Comment: Hi Ahmad, Ajax can call a php script and return the data to the user without having to reload the page so you could for example create a function to check every 30 seconds if any new messages have come in for said user and then make an alert viewable with javascript, however without seeing you code there maybe better solutions but try this to get you started: 

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp
You will need to learn a little about ajax to get this to work.

Comment: just a little hint, if you provide a little more info on how your system works and how it is displayed to users you may get more detailed replies but from what you have given us there are too many options.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Make respective functions and Put conditions

```
if(InsertMessage())
{
  SendMessage();
}

function InsertMessage()
{
   //query and code to insert message 
   //return true if success 
   //return false if fail   
}

function SendMessage()
{
  //Code to send message
}
```

Comment: This is really complicated, explain more please.